# How to define loss in LSTM that has series of vectors as input?

Tags: time-series, loss-functions, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I asked this question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042272/how-to-implement-lstm-network-with-vector-input-in-each-time-step) but didn't get any answer, so I am posting it here as I believe second part of original question fits CrossValidated more.

So, as original question states, I am trying to create generative LSTM which I will train on series of musical notes. Each vector is 88-dimensional (there are 88 keys on most pianos) and each element of a vector represents one pitch.

'0' means tone is off, '1' means tone is on. Additionally, if the same note is played again then it becomes '2' (vectors truncated for brevity):

```
[0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 2 0 0]
[0 0 2 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0]
...
```

So, third tone here is played first time and it lasts 2t, then same tone is played again, and again it lasts 2t, and so on. If this all would be 1s, I would not be able to distinguish if it is one tone that lasts 5t, or two or more tones that last shorter amount of time.

Those are input vectors, each input vector is one time step in a network. Output vectors are the same thing, only shifted by one step to the right (+1) so I will have something like this:

```
[0 0 1 0 0] -> LSTM cell -> [0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0] -> LSTM cell -> [0 0 2 0 0]
[0 0 2 0 0] -> LSTM cell -> [0 0 2 0 0]
[0 0 2 0 0] -> LSTM cell -> [0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0] -> LSTM cell -> [0 0 0 0 0]
```

Of course, recurrent connections pass from one LSTM cell to another (that is not shown on this ASCII sketch).

My question is, how do I define loss function in this case?

I also have another representation where '0' means tone is off, '0.5' means tone is on, and '1' means tone is finished. Would that be any different in terms of defining loss function?